# Copying the CiviCRM installation in a different machine

Tags: wordpress, database, installation, civicrm.settings.php

I am trying to make a copy of my CiviCRM installation on WordPress in a different machine. I ma mainly trying this just as a practice for future upgrading of CiviCRM versions and also as a backup.

I am caught up in a deadlock. both these options are failing. I don't which of the two options I should proceed with and how.

In machine 2,

1. I installed wordpress. created a database for Civicrm through PHPMyAdmin. copied the data from original database to new one. Activiating CiviCRM fails.
2. I installed wordpress. created a database for Civicrm through PHPMyAdmin. Activated CiviCRM. Tried copying the data alone from original database to new one. It fails with below error " Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'"

INSERT INTO `civicrm_acl` (`id`, `name`, `deny`, `entity_table`, `entity_id`, `operation`, `object_table`, `object_id`, `acl_table`, `acl_id`, `is_active`) VALUES
(1, 'Edit All Contacts', 0, 'civicrm_acl_role', 1, 'Edit', 'civicrm_saved_search', 0, NULL, NULL, 1),
(2, 'Core ACL', 0, 'civicrm_acl_role', 0, 'All', 'access CiviMail subscribe/unsubscribe pages', NULL, NULL, NULL, 1),
(3, 'Core ACL', 0, 'civicrm_acl_role', 0, 'All', 'access all custom data', NULL, NULL, NULL, 1),
(4, 'Core ACL', 0, 'civicrm_acl_role', 0, 'All', 'make online contributions', NULL, NULL, NULL, 1),
(5, 'Core ACL', 0, 'civicrm_acl_role', 0, 'All', 'make online pledges', NULL, NULL, NULL, 1),
(6, 'Core ACL', 0, 'civicrm_acl_role', 0, 'All', 'profile listings and forms', NULL, NULL, NULL, 1),
(7, 'Core ACL', 0, 'civicrm_acl_role', 0, 'All', 'view event info', NULL, NULL, NULL, 1),
(8, 'Core ACL', 0, 'civicrm_acl_role', 0, 'All', 'register for events', NULL, NULL, NULL, 1),
(9, 'Core ACL', 0, 'civicrm_acl_[...]
MySQL said: Documentation

## 1062 - Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Moving+the+database+using+phpMyAdmin

I found this useful. Getting it done through phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 3):

See documentation on moving an existing installation to a new server or location on this link: https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Moving+an+Existing+Installation+to+a+New+Server+or+Location

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you didn't delete the existing CiviCRM MySQL database before importing the new one.

Comment: I think I deleted it. But which is the correct approach? 1 or 2?

Comment: Approach 1 is correct.  Please see the documentation that Kboy references for details.